# Adding custom taxonomy terms to WP from a front end form

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, taxonomy

I'm trying to add terms to my custom taxonomy from a front-end form. I managed to create the form populate the select by values from another custom post type's posts. But I think that my form handler is not working... When I hit submit the form just takes me to "http://therealaddress.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" and nothing happens (no new term to the taxonomy, no forwarding to the page I want)... (and yes, I changed therealaddress.com to hide my real address, it's not the wrong address :D)

I would like to forward the user back to the page where the form is after the submission.

My form handling part looks like this in my themes funtions.php

```
function horse_taxonomy_adder() {
    // splitting the select options value from "horses-real-name:Horses Real Name" to "horses-real-name" and "Horses Real Name"
    $horsename = ( $_POST['horsename'] );
    $hn_slug = split(':', $horsename)[0];
    $hn_name = split(':', $horsename)[1];

    wp_insert_term(
        'hn_name', // the term
        'hevoset', // the taxonomy
        array(
            'slug' => $hn_slug,
        )
    );
    // add the admin notice
    $admin_notice = "success";
    // redirect the user to the page called "Hallinta"
    $page = get_page_by_title('hallinta');
    $this->wp_redirect(get_permalink($page->ID));

    exit;
}

add_action('admin_post_add_horsetaxonomy','horse_taxonomy_adder');
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form action="http://therealaddress.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="horse_taxonomy_adder">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Valitse hevonen jolle päiväkirja luodaan</label>
        <select name="horsename">
            <?php
            global $post;
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'hevonen');
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <option value="<? echo $post->post_name; ?>:<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Lisää päiväkirja</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You are asking that you want to submit the form by select the value. right??

Comment: I would like to use the submitted value of the select to create a new taxonomy term yes :)

Comment: @Heidi Does the form is available to the anonymous user or just to the logged-in users?

Comment: @Heidi You are using wrong action tag in `add_action()`. Replace `admin_post_add_horsetaxonomy ` with `admin_post_ horse_taxonomy_adder ` which may solves your issue if you still have it.

Comment: Huege thanks for helping with this problem too, form is only available for logged-in users. I'll try your suggestion.